# HLA compilation - can build directory be specified?

Tags: hla

By default, compiling `hla filename.hla` builds an executable in the currently directory.  Can a different directory be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- HLA (High Level Assembler - HLABE back end, LD linker)
  Version 2.16 build 4463 (prototype)
- Ubuntu 20.10

***SOLUTION***

- This can be specified by using the option `-x:name Executable output filename (does not append ".exe").` Found in the hla help, under the "Assembler and Linker Control" section.
- To change the output directory consider `-x:name` to be `-x:/path/to/name` instead.

***EXAMPLE***

```
user@host:~/example$ ls
src  bin
user@host:~/example$ cd src
user@host:~/example/src$ ls
filename.hla
user@host:~/example/src$ hla -x:../bin/filename.x filename.hla
user@host:~/example/src$ ls
src.hla  src.o
user@host:~/example/src$ cd ../bin
user@host:~/example/bin$ ls
filename.x
user@host:~/example/bin$
```